# Excel does not save author, company, or manager

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am using Excel 2013, and am playing with the meta info. I have set title, tags, comment, status categories, subject, hyperlink base, company, manager, and author. The last 3 of these are quietly blanked, when I return to the info, but only after I save.

File is saving as .xlsx

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fond the mythical, “Don't do what I say” button, and turned it off. (at least for this feature.)

Click on
`Allow this information to be saved in your file`, it is referring to the personal information, not the settings.

[image]

Comment: Maybe it makes you fight for this, because they embed other personal info that you would not want to share, but now you have asked for it.